# Binding Issue between VB and C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

In C# I have the following code

```
txtCode.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", _bsDetail, "Code", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

In VB.NET

```
txtCode.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", _bsDetail, "Code", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
```

In C# I can call this code before setting the datasource on the bindingsource, in VB.NET I have to assign the datasource before calling this code. I get the following error in VB.NET

Cannot bind to the property or column Code on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember'

Is there a way I can call this code before assigning the datasource in VB.NET?

Comment: In C#, are you sure that the BindingSource.DataSource isn't applied in the Designer-generated code? (i.e.: check the .designer.cs file).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I am sure, the bindingsource is created thru code

Comment: Setup a break point on the line and watch what the value is of `_bsDetail`. My guess is that `_bsDetail.Code` does not exist or is nothing.

Comment: @David _bsDetail has been created as is not Nothing. There isn't a property on the bindingsource called Code (_bsDetail.Code), this is the column in the datasource to which the control needs to bind to.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way I can call this code before assigning the datasource in VB.NET?

Yes there is and it will be the same code sequence that would be used in C#.  There is nothing inherent in C# that allows what you have described.

To prove this to yourself, create a new C# Winform project and add the following code to Form1.

```
BindingSource bs;
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    bs = new BindingSource();
    Debugger.Break();
    Binding b = new Binding("Text", bs, "Code", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    this.DataBindings.Add(b);
}
```

Now run the code and when the debugger *breaks*, step through the code.  You will see the error occur on the last line.  Here is an excerpt form the stack trace.  The error occurs in the [CheckBinding method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/BindToObject.cs,2846fbe6b9533ebf) since the `BindingSource` has not been assigned a `DataSource` that exposes a `Code` property.

> at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.CheckBinding()
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.SetBindingManagerBase(BindingManagerBase lManager)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.SetListManager(BindingManagerBase bindingManagerBase)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.ListManagerBindingsCollection.AddCore(Binding dataBinding)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindingsCollection.Add(Binding binding)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.UpdateBinding(BindingContext newBindingContext, Binding binding)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.SetBindableComponent(IBindableComponent value)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.ControlBindingsCollection.AddCore(Binding dataBinding)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindingsCollection.Add(Binding binding)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.ControlBindingsCollection.Add(Binding binding)

The binding check can be suppressed by placing the `BindingSource` in an *initializing* state.  `BindingSource` implements the [ISupportInitialize Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize?view=netframework-4.8) that exposes the [BeginInit Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.system-componentmodel-isupportinitialize-begininit?view=netframework-4.8).  Replace the `OnLoad` code with the following:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    bs = new BindingSource();
    ISupportInitialize isi = (ISupportInitialize)bs;
    Debugger.Break();
    isi.BeginInit();
    Binding b = new Binding("Text", bs, "Code", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    this.DataBindings.Add(b);
    isi.EndInit();
}
```

Run the code and again step through the code in the debugger.  You will see that the error does not occur at the `DataBindings.Add` statement, but rather it occurs at the [EndInit Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.system-componentmodel-isupportinitialize-endinit?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_BindingSource_System_ComponentModel_ISupportInitialize_EndInit) at which point `CheckBindings` is ultimately called and fails because no data source was provided.

> at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.CheckBinding()
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.DataSource_Initialized(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.OnInitialized()
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize.EndInit()

So the simplified code pattern is:

1. Create a BindingSource instance.
2. Call BeginInit on the BindingSource.
3. Create/add all your bindings against the BindingSource.
4. Set the BindingSource.DataSource Property.
5. Call EndInit on the BindingSource.

This pattern is independent of the language used.